# Bones appear in Layout workspace but not Animation workspace

Tags: animation, bones

I have a model that I am trying to animate. I set the bones to display "In Front" in the Viewport Display settings so that I could see the bones easily. This works in the Layout workspace:

[image: Layout workspace]

But when I go into the Animation workspace, they do not appear:
[image]

If I switch to Wireframe shading in the Animation workspace, it looks like the bones are not rendered at all:

[image]

Does anyone know why this might be?

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the animation tab, created a new one, and the issue was fixed.